# Como posso passar um parâmetro com redirecionamento o clicar em um botão

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando enviar um parâmetro para um outra página `.php` ao clicar em um botão, não gostaria que esse parâmetro seja exibido no navegador, já tentei com esse código aqui, mas o parâmetro ficou exposto.

```
    function Oportunidade(pPar){
        var url = 'iAutenticacao.php?IdOportunidade='+pPar; 
        window.location.href = url;         
     }
```

Também já tinha feito algumas tentativas com ajax, mas sem sucesso.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Vi que usa PHP, poderia usar o padrão MVC pra fazer isso. https://goo.gl/wtkKBz

Comment: Eu acho que o javascript sempre irá mostrar o parâmetro em algum lugar do navegador. Você não deveria se preocupar tanto com isso. Se esse parâmetro for algo sensível para a segurança da aplicação, ele não deveria ser usado no javascript.

Comment: Olá, @AndreiCoelho, você está coberto de razão

Comment: Eu só não digo CERTEZA, por que realmente eu não tenho certeza disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar esse botão dentro de um mini form.

```
<form action="iAutenticacao.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="idOportunidade" value="1234" />
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Essa é a única forma simples de colocar a ação do jeito que você quer, sem que o parâmetro apareça na URL.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @cHida, ajudou,